# What is the best way to separate data from an array and how to synchronize arrays?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, dimensions

Sorry if the title is not clear enough! Hard to summarize my need!

I have 3 arrays. Two with coordinates (longitude & latitude) and the 3rd which contain data. The coordinates are complete, and the data has some 'nan'. When I use them as they are with `scipy.gridata`, the resulting plot is fill of blanked areas because of the nan.

So, in order to improve, I need to remove the nan from the array with data and also synchronized with the coordinates arrays.

I learned to find the indices of my numbers in an array, to separate them from the nan, using

```
indices_of_numbers = np.argwhere(~np.isnan(my_data))
```

All arrays are 1D, and when I use

```
my_data_nan_free = my_data[indices_of_numbers]
```

the resulting array is 2D, and causes error with  `griddata`

I can remove the extra dimension with `np.squeeze`.

My question is if this is the best way to do that?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Look at at `indices_of_numbers`.  What's its `shape`?

Comment: Can you give an example of some input data and the corresponding desired output?

Comment: hpaulj:  the 'my_data' shape is (36, ), and the 'indices_of_numbers' come out with (31, 1).

Comment: Jay Mody: an example could be: x = [ 2, 3, 2, 4], y = [3, 3, 2, 2], z = [1 nan nan 2], so, after synchronizing, x_2 = [2, 4], y_2 = [3, 2], z_2 = [1, 2].  I think the way I get there is clumsy... I would like to learn a more 'elegant' way of doing this, and curious why the extra dimenion pop up! (I'm migrating form Matlab!!)